# formatting number columns in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable, formatting

Hi I am new to datatables and I was wondering if there was an easy way to format numbers to have 2 decimal places etc.  (234.12) in jquery datatables

```
  { mData: 'CostInDollar', mRender: Helper.NumberHelper.renderMoney, sTitle: 'Cost', sWidth: '10%', bSortable: true, sType: 'numeric', bVisible: true },
```

We can render it as numeric but the default decimal place for this is 1 place after.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks